# Negate a RegEx when using OR `|`

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a RegEx pattern

```
^(\d+|\w+-\d+)$
```

How do I match all those strings which **do not match this pattern**?

Comment: If lookarounds are supported, you may use a neg. lookahead: `(?!^\d+|\w+-\d+$)`.

Comment: @Tushar I will be using this pattern in RequestMapping (Java Spring)

Comment: @Jan For ^(\d+|\w+-\d+)$ , (?!^(\d+|\w+-\d+)$) doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @ViH What language will you be implementing this pattern with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into it and try to understand that. Logically it will be like this. Lets say if have a condition which say either `X` or `Y` then negation of its will be neither `X` and nor `Y`.

**`X or Y`** `negation` will be equal to **`Neither X and Nor Y`**.

For that you can try this.

[**Regex code demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ytVuvV/1)

**Regex:** `^(?!\d+$)(?!\w+-\d+$).*$`

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.** `(?!\d+$)` negative look-ahead for digits till the end of string.
>
> **3.** `(?!\w+-\d+$)` negative look-ahead for `words` then `-` and then `digits` till the end.
>
> **4.** `.*$` match all till then end.

Comment: Thanks, Good Explanation!

Comment: It can be also written shorter as `^(?!(?:\w+-)?\d+$).*$`. And if there are newlines, do not forget the `DOTALL` or `Singleline` modifier.